# Create a list of 2 subdirectories each from a directory using "find"

Tags: ubuntu, find

I need to compile a list of directories for later backup with Restic. I need exactly two directories inside each subdomain to be included in that list. Everything else should not be backed up.

The directory structure is as follows:

```
subdomain1.domain.tld
|- other_directory1
|- public_html
   |- backup1
   |- backup2
   |- no_backup1
   |- no_backup2
   |- no_backup3
subdomain2.domain.tld
|- other_directory1
|- public_html
   |- backup1
   |- backup2
   |- no_backup1
   |- no_backup2
   |- no_backup3
subdomain3.domain.tld
|- other_directory1
|- public_html
   |- backup1
   |- backup2
   |- no_backup1
   |- no_backup2
   |- no_backup3
```

At the end I would like my list to look like this:

```
/path/to/my/subdomains/subdomain1.domain.tld/public_html/backup1
/path/to/my/subdomains/subdomain1.domain.tld/public_html/backup2
/path/to/my/subdomains/subdomain2.domain.tld/public_html/backup1
/path/to/my/subdomains/subdomain2.domain.tld/public_html/backup2
/path/to/my/subdomains/subdomain3.domain.tld/public_html/backup1
/path/to/my/subdomains/subdomain3.domain.tld/public_html/backup2
```

So far I have this:

```
find /path/to/my/subdomains -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d -printf '%f\n' | sort | xargs readlink -f > list.txt
```

which gives me a list of all my subdomains, but not `public_html/backup1` and `public_html/backup1` of each directory. Any advice how to proceed from here? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look for directories whose name starts with `backup`, and print their full path:

```
find /path/to/my/subdomains -type d -name 'backup*'
```

If you want to explicitly list the full names of all directories to back up:

```
find /path/to/my/subdomains -type d \( -name backup1 -o -name backup2 \)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be more explicit as to where to find those directories, in the `zsh` shell, you can do:

```
print -rC1 /path/to/my/subdomains/*/public_html/(backup1|backup2)(N/)
```

to print them or:

```
dirs=(
  /path/to/my/subdomains/*/public_html/(backup1|backup2)(N/)
)
```

to store them in an array to use as `(( $#dirs )) && my-backup-cmd $dirs` for instance.

But if the point is to print a `backup1` and `backup2` for each `public_html` directory, regardless of whether they exist or not, you can do:

```
print -rC1 /path/to/my/subdomains/*/public_html(N-/e[
  'reply=($REPLY/{backup1,backup2})'])
```

That is using the `e`valuation glob qualifier to return those two paths for each `public_html` directory.

Or:

```
() {
  print -rC1 $^argv/{backup1,backup2}
} /path/to/my/subdomains/*/public_html(N-/)
```

This time using an anoymous function that takes those `public_html` dirs as arguments and appends both `/backup1` and `/backup2` to them.